# Anyway to get app info into OAuth Dialog

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-oauth

I know this has been posted before, but I haven't seen a definitive answer only a bunch of "I thinks" or no answer. The [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) shows a much more in depth dialog box with information about the app from the developer tool. However, now I seem to only get a box asking for only the permissions.

This is going to be a page tab, so the user won't necessarily see the App Details page and I want to describe to them why I'm asking for what I'm asking for.

Answer points go to either A)How to do it, or B)Documentation showing it can't be done.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Facebook Documentation was out of date. It has since been updated. 
App information will not be in the dialog box.